# How send photos with django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Im new working with django-tastypie.
Works fine for send data with json and i don't know how send files with django-tastypie and json and how test this functionality

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: You dont sent actual files. You just send the absolute urls to the file.

Answer (score 0):

[django-tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a REST framework, it works with entities serialized in some format (JSON, XML, etc).

Technically you can serialize a image an use tastypie, but it will not be easy or elegant.

Instead, you can use django to upload a image and if needed you can use the file reference (as an URL) in your entities with tastypie without problems.